# C# Insert Advice Please

Tags: c#, mysql, crud

Hi I would love some help and advice on a C# insert statement to insert into a selected table.

So far i have made this insert function for one table, but would like help to make one that inserts values into a selected table.

EDIT: Updated code, what I have so far but has issues

```
       public bool Insert(Dictionary<string, string> values, string tableName)
    {

       SqlDataAdapter adapter;

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {

              string query = "INSERT INTO" tableName "VALUES({string.Join("," values)})";

               using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))

               {
                conn.Open();
                adapter = command.ExecuteAdapter();
               }
            }
            return adapter;
   }
 }
}
```

This is my new function which i want to create to insert values into the selected table

```
public bool insert(Dictionary<string, string> values, string tableName)
        {


            SqlDataAdapter adapter; 

 //statment that takes the input which contains vaules, which are           indexed by the colum names
            //as well as a string which represents the table name



            //conenction open

            //exucute


            //return bool status of insert
```

Any help would be great please, ii haven't really stared the new statement only the psudo code.

Comment: search for 'looping through dictionary'. and 'insert using sqldatadapter'. i know you can do it. ; )

Comment: Thanks I will give that a go

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    public bool Insert(Dictionary<string, string> values, string tableName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()
                {
                    Connection = conn,
                    CommandText = $"INSERT INTO {tableName} VALUES({string.Join(", ", values)})"
                };
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Also, if you program in .NET I suggest you look a little bit over .NET coding styles and capitalization conventions, it'll make your life way easier in the future. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help, all seems good although getting an error on   `CommandText = $"INSERT INTO  ',' {tableName} VALUES({string.Join("," values)})"` tableName is a table selected from a drop down list from my getAll statment. The error is haveing ',' missing which i have added but then i get invailed number of member delcarations.